# Debugging using hardware - can I automatically uninstall?

Tags: android, debugging

I'm a newbie at Android programming and I'm setting up my tablet to debug my software, as the emulator just seems to be too slow.

I've just set up my android tablet to debug but I've noticed that when I stop the debugging, it doesn't actually delete the app I've installed.

So I'm just wondering, is there an option in eclipse that'll automatically uninstall the app from my tablet after I stop debugging and if not, is it just a matter of uninstalling it manually from the tablet settings? If it's the latter, would that completely remove everything? I just don't want to have my tablet start filling up with junk generated from my debugging sessions.

Comment: No-one has asked why?  The only way you will get "junk" is if your app generates it.  There is no need to uninstall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no option to automatically uninstall it from eclipse.

You have two options to uninstall it. One of them (which you mentioned) is to delete it from settings on your device.

The other is to use adb command. Go to your SDK folder, inside the `platform-tools` directory and open a command prompt (in windows you can use shift+right click in the folder to open it directly in that folder) then run this command:

```
adb uninstall com.your.apps.package.name
```

But use your own package name. That will uninstall the app from your device and is likely quicker than using the settings on your device.